# Bridge network using wifi hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge, wireless-bridge

How to create a bridge between my wifi hotspot and LAN connection.
What I want-: I am in university they give limited internet speed per IP.
When I created a hotspot from my Linux or Windows laptop speed is divided between laptop and connected hotspot because laptop assigns an IP address to my hotspot connected device. I want that all devices have to assign an IP address to the university server, not my laptop. So that I get university limited speed to all devices.How did I do it Please Help?

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is to basically put a wireless access point on the university network? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Ben Franske

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a single wired ethernet connection. Get a small [switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FNFSPY) to connect to that port and you should be good.

NOTES:

- Do not get a wireless router and connect it. This can cause tons of
  problems if it starts handing out IPs and you will get a visit from
  some unhappy IT friends
- Your university may limit your bandwidth per-port which means you get
  no extra speed with this solution
- Many university policies do not allow routing/switching devices like this at all. Students often think it might be fun to connect one port to another and bring down a network.

Comment: They limit connection by IP not port because when I run multiple VM's in PC  it gave download speed which university provided in all VM's.